# Get model field values from FK related objects

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I've got a structure of FK related objects that looks somewhat like that:

```
class Object3(models.Model):
    ...
    requirement = models.ManyToManyField(Requirement, blank=True)


class Object2(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Object3, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requirement = models.ManyToManyField(Requirement, blank=True)


class Object1(models.Model):
    ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Object2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requirement = models.ManyToManyField(Requirement, blank=True)


class Requirement(models.Model):
    ...
```

All of those object have the same non-required field, which is a ManyToManyField, it's basically a requirement that can be set on either level of the structure.

What I need to do is when I set the m2m field on the highest level of the structure, Object3, I need related Object2 and Object1 to set the m2m identically, same if I set it on Object2 instance, I need it to be set on the related Object1 instances.

What is the most Django-ish way to achieve that?

I hope my explanation is clear enough, I'll be more than happy to provide any more information.

I've been pulling my hair out with this simple task, but I can't seem to come up with a good solution, hopefully with your help I'll be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Foreignkeys to the requirement would be better.

But you can add requirements to each object with `Object1.requirement.add(requirement)` and remove them with `Object1.requirement.remove(requirement)` so in theory every time you change one you could also apply it to the rest.

Comment: Ii think m2m is the only way to go, because multiple requirements can be set to either object instance. 

I tried using .add in overriden save() method, but the problem is that I would need to add a queryset like that, like self.requirement.add(self.parent.requirement) which doesn't seem to work, also tried qs union, but it throws errors.

Comment: try setting a related name and using that or Requirement in the query might need a capital letter

Comment: Hmmm I don't think there's a problem with that, related name would be used if we wanted to access i.e Object2 instance through Requirements instance.